# Python timedelta: microseconds vs milliseconds confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

I have what appears to be a very silly question.

My impression is that the `timedelta.microseconds` attribute really returns milliseconds (at least in Python 3.10).

Running the following code:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import sleep

print(sys.version)
start: datetime = datetime.now()
sleep(3) # time.sleep takes a non-keyword "secs" argument aka seconds - see docstring
end: datetime = datetime.now()
delta: timedelta = (end - start)
print(delta)
print(delta.microseconds)
print(delta.microseconds / 1000)
print(delta.seconds)
```

... will print out something in the lines of (my comments at end of line):

```
3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] # full version info for reference
0:00:03.003650 # representation of the delta as requested
3650 # isn't that >> milliseconds <<<? aka roughly 3 seconds * 1000 ?
3.65 # dividing the delta by 1000 roughly gives me the original argument
3 # accessing the "seconds" attribute instead works as expected --> 3 seconds (roughly)
```

I couldn't find anything to clarify this for me in the official 3.10 datetime doc [page](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.microseconds), which makes me wonder whether this is an actual naming bug or I'm overlooking something obvious.

Note also that the timedelta class doesn't appear to have a "milliseconds" attribute I can use for comparison.

Comment: I just tested with other figures and I get the problem now - the "3" in the micros was a misleading accident.

Comment: @jasonharper I guess I should most likely use total_seconds() and manipulate it whichever way I want in case I want it converted in this narrow use case then. Would you like to add a short answer with your explanation? Not entirely sure whether this question really has any value to the community though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

timedelta stores days, seconds and microseconds. The microseconds you see is the microseconds part of the value, not the seconds converted to microseconds.

Source - https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects